# Google cloud platform vs other hosting

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I always host wordpress with Godaddy and bluehost but now my client asked if it will be possible to host it in Google cloud platform if it is better.
My question are:

1- What are the benefit I will get comparing to other hosting?

2- what is the annual price? I checked it in Google but it is not clearly mentioned. It only says you pay based on usage.
https://cloud.google.com/php/tutorials/wordpress-app-engine-flexible

3- Does they provide an easy access to cpanel ( file manager – database and phpmyadmin).

4- Do I need to have developer skills to use it? Or they will provide 24 hours support?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. That's totally different. Google cloud platform using Cloud server and it can't compare with traditional shared hosting and of course the fee will be more expensive.
2. Yes, you can check directly via that link. I never use Google, but I use Azure. My experience Azure is very costly, but the deployment is very easy. The cost that I need to pay at that time is 6 times higher than my shared hosting. So, I moved back to shared hosting again.
3. You can login directly to the server
4. You need to know about managing server